# Objects versus Arrays

Tags: php, mysqli, benchmarking

I am working on a site at the moment, and there is a concentrated focus on efficiency and speed in loading, processing and such like.

I'm using the mysqli extension to get my database bits and bobs, but I'm wondering what's the best / most efficient way of outputting my dataset?

At the moment I'm using $mysqli->fetch_assoc() and a foreach(). Having read http://www.phpbench.com I know that counting my data first makes a difference. (I'm going to optimise after build)

My question is, which is quicker for getting a resultset into a php data thing. Creating an object? A numerical array? An associative array? My thoughts are an object, but I'm unsure.

Just curious, as I'm not familiar with the PHP internals :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a small benchmark in PHP documentation under `mysql_fetch_object`'s comments:

```
SELECT * FROM bench... (mysql_fetch_object)
```

> Query time: 5.40725040436
>   Fetching time: 16.2730708122 (avg: 1.32130565643E-5)
>   Total time: 21.6803212166

```
SELECT * FROM bench... (mysql_fetch_array)
```

> Query time: 5.37693023682
>   Fetching time: 10.3851644993 (avg: 7.48886537552E-6)
>   Total time: 15.7620947361

```
SELECT * FROM bench... (mysql_fetch_assoc)
```

> Query time: 5.345921278
>   Fetching time: 10.6170959473 (avg: 7.64049530029E-6)
>   Total time: 15.9630172253

Fetching an object is slowest, fetching a numeric array is probably a bit faster than using `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`, but the difference is negligible. In fact, `mysql_fetch_array` fetches both assoc and numeric, and it's faster than `mysql_fetch_assoc`, go figure.. But if you're after performance, just don't use `mysql_fetch_object`.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual page of [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

> **Note: Performance**
>
> Speed-wise, the function is identical to mysql_fetch_array(), and almost as quick as 
>   mysql_fetch_row() (the difference is insignificant)

As the benchmark given by Tatu suggests, there is a slight difference, but keep in mind the numbers have been cumulated from 100 consecutive queries. I'd say your strategy of not bothering now and optimize later is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a numerical array is likely to be the most lightweight, followed by associative array, and then an object.  I don't think the differences will add up to much, so whichever syntax you're most comfortable with is best.